# Centering a div after a float underneath on browser resize

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following html-

```
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="page-header" id="property_head">A cool title</h1> 
  <div class="row text_img">
    <div class="span9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span3" id="activity"><img src="http://some/img.png"></div>
        <div class="span5" id="activity_text"><h3 class="text_title">Great Title</h3><br><p class="lead">Foo</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

and the following css-

```
.text_img {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;

}

#activity {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#activity_text {
  float: right;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

I'm using bootrap for `container` `page-header` `row` and `span3/5`. When I resize the browser below for ex 300px `#activity_text` positions itself underneath `#activity` which is what I want.

I'm using media queries and I would like when the breakdown of the text positioning itself beneath the img, for the img to center above the text and remain that way for all width's below (using a media query).

After trying multiple approaches I am unsure of the CSS to make this work. Thanks for your atteniton. Take a look at the attached.[image] [image]

NOTE: Changing the colors of the background to help notice the media query breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the specific media query you'll just have to remove any floats, give it a width & margin:auto.  e.g. at your desired media query max-width:

```
#activity {
    float:none;
    width:50%; /* or whatever you want it to be */
    margin:auto;
}
```

Depending how Bootstrap CSS is setup you may have to add `!important` to one or all of the CSS above to make sure it does what you want it to do at that media query point.

Also I wasn't sure if the activity_text automatically went underneath at that point, so here's the CSS you would need at the same media query for that to work:

```
#activity_text {
    float:none;
    width:100%;
}
```